# Extracting commentary from match video

Tags: signal-processing

I'm working on event classification for sports videos and as a part of it, I was looking to extract information from the commentator's excited tone. Since the frequency of human voice is bound by a range, can I just extract that from the audio signal on a time scale and work with that? I've tried using the fdesign.bandpass function, but don't know how to proceed further with it.

Or is there a better approach to doing this?

Comment: "extract information from the commentator's excited tone" what information? the fact that the commentator is excited? or the words he's saying while excited?

Comment: in either case, I suspect that no, you can't just bandpass the signal to find the excited part. most commercial broadcasts will compress the hell out of their signals so loudness detection might not even be good enough (although it could). You'll likely need a statistical classifier to actually make this happen.

Comment: Just the excited tone, actually. But since it's just a part of the classification process, I thought I'd see what the commentator voice signal looks like too. But given that the audio signal contains the entire spectrum, wouldn't it be to possible to just extract the frequencies from say 30hz to 30khz and represent them on a time scale?

Comment: Yes, it would, extracting frequency information and plotting it against time is called a spectrogram. I'm afraid I don't understand exactly what you mean when you say "excited tone". Also I should point out that 30-30kHz is unnecessary, human hearing only goes from 20-20kHz to start with and human voice is only from like 80-5000hZ.

Comment: Oh thank you! Excited tone as in when let's say a goal is scored, so the commentator's voice would be louder. So I wanted to see if I can get that information. That is the points where the voice level say exceeds a threshold. So I wanted to get, say amplitudes, just from those set of frequencies. I'm sorry if I'm not able to put across my point clearly.